# MySQL Query with subQuery as an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, subquery

I need to do a few mysql queries but i would rather get all the data i need in 1 query instead of multiple.

how would I turn this into a sub query?

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY categoryName ASC
SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY locationName ASC
```

Comment: this is any relationship between categories and locations?

Comment: A subquery of what? Are these tables related in any way? Do they have similar columns? What should your output be?

Comment: These tables are not related at all, I would like to just get all categories into an array and all locations into an array in 1 query if possibe., thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM categories,(SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY locationName ASC) AS location ORDER BY categoryName ASC
```

Comment: That will produce a cartesian product of `categories` and `locations`. There's no gain from wrapping `locations` as a derived table, since it could just go directly in the `FROM` clause via join (if these tables even have a relationship)

Comment: Three tables have a relationship, SELECT * FROM categories SELECT * FROM categories_attributes WHERE categoryID = categoryID, SeLECT * FROM categories_meta WHERE categoryID = categoryID

Comment: Categories Structure = categoryID,categoryName,categoryUri
Categories_Attributes Struction = attributeID, categoryID, attributeLabel, attributeValue
Categories_Meta Structure = metaID, categoryID, metaLabel, metaValue